# How to use Xlib and OpenGL with Python and NVidia card?

Tags: python, opengl, x11, pyopengl

I copied this code from another thread and it works fine.

```
from Xlib import X, display
from OpenGL import GL, GLX
from OpenGL.raw._GLX import struct__XDisplay
from ctypes import *

# some python-xlib code...
pd = display.Display()
pw = pd.screen().root.create_window(50, 50, 200, 200, 0,
                                pd.screen().root_depth,
                                X.InputOutput, X.CopyFromParent)
pw.map()

# ensure that the XID is valid on the server
pd.sync()

# get the window XID
xid = pw.__resource__()

# a separate ctypes Display object for OpenGL.GLX
xlib = cdll.LoadLibrary('libX11.so')
xlib.XOpenDisplay.argtypes = [c_char_p]
xlib.XOpenDisplay.restype = POINTER(struct__XDisplay)
d = xlib.XOpenDisplay("")

# use GLX to create an OpenGL context on the same window XID
elements = c_int()
configs = GLX.glXChooseFBConfig(d, 0, None, byref(elements))
w = GLX.glXCreateWindow(d, configs[0], c_ulong(xid), None)
context = GLX.glXCreateNewContext(d, configs[0], GLX.GLX_RGBA_TYPE, None, True)
GLX.glXMakeContextCurrent(d, w, w, context)

# some python-opengl code....
GL.glShadeModel(GL.GL_FLAT)
GL.glClearColor(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0)

GL.glViewport(0, 0, 200, 200)
GL.glMatrixMode(GL.GL_PROJECTION)
GL.glLoadIdentity()
GL.glOrtho(-1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0)

GL.glClear(GL.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
GL.glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 0.0)
GL.glRectf(-0.8, -0.8, 0.8, 0.8)

# assume we got a double buffered fbConfig and show what we drew
GLX.glXSwapBuffers(d, w)
```

Now I would like to generate an OpenGL texture from X Pixmap. So instead of w = GLX.glXCreateWindow(), I use pix = GLX.glXCreatePixmap().

Then I wrote

```
GLX.glXBindTexImageEXT(d, pix, GLX.GLX_FRONT_EXT, None)
```

And I get an error: ctypes.ArgumentError: argument1: : expected LP_struct__XDisplay instance instead of LP_struct__XDisplay

glXBindTexImageEXT() function is defined in my _GLX_NV.py (I have an NVidia card). I think the problem comes from the double definition of struct__XDisplay in _GLX.py and _GLX_NV.py

If I change d by:

```
display = _GLX_NV.glXGetCurrentDisplayEXT()
```

I got a BadMatch, X_GLXVendorPrivate

Do you have an idea, how I could solve my problem and transfer a X11 Pixmap to OpenGL texture in python?